# An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine when downloading artifacts from Nexus

Tags: java, sockets, nexus

I'm using a Windows Server 2008 R2 t2.large AWS instance to run Nexus repository manager, jenkins and other tools. I have a java process that downloads artifacts (.zip files size 2.6 GB) from Nexus to the local repo in the instance. The file starts downloading but after a certain amount of time, the connection gets aborted and reconnected. So the downloaded file is lost. In the end a partial file is downloaded. When looking at Nexus logs, it says:

> An established connection was aborted by the software in your host
>   machine, at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method) at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)

I have tried disabling the Firewall but still facing the issue. All the processes I'm running are 64-bit. Is this because of some connection Timeout imposed by the OS? Or any limit on downloading larger artifacts? 
Tried setting TCPIP properties in regedit still without luck!